# MySQL query with dynamic parameters (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a MySQL query to handle dynamic parameters.
I have 3 selects, each select is multiple:

[image]

I want that the query that is in the back to check which one is multiple and add the condition in the where clause.

I cannot figure it out! Please!

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried to "figure it out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each select is multiple, you can use an array for each one, splitted by comma.
Example

```
var array;
array['AreaNegocio'  ] = "1, 3, 5";
array['CentroDeCosto'] = "21, 35, 500";
array['GrupoDeCuenta'] = "20, 51, 123";
```

When you get the request on backend, you can check which param arraived.

Example:

```
if (isset($param['AreaNegocio']) {
     $query .= " AND column IN ('".$param['AreaNegocio']."')";
}
```

and so on

Comment: This needs placeholder values or escaping, and it has neither.

Answer (score -1):

It is not completly clear what you want to achieve. You have 3 html select tags but you want to create a stmt which selects from one table?

```
<?php

define('SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('PASSWORD', "");
define('DATABASE', "jcalendar");

$vals = array(
filter_input(INPUT_GET,'selectField1'), // col1 - id
filter_input(INPUT_GET,'selectField2'), // col2 - date
filter_input(INPUT_GET,'selectField3'), // col3 - time
);

$query = "SELECT * from bookings";

if($vals[0]||$vals[1]||$vals[2])
{
    // Create connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, DB_USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    if($vals[0] && !$vals[1] && !$vals[2]){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query." WHERE id= ? ");
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("s",$vals[0])) exit();
    }elseif($vals[0] && $vals[1] && !$vals[2]){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query." WHERE id=? AND date=?");
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("ss",$vals[0],$vals[1])) exit();
    }elseif($vals[0] && !$vals[1] && $vals[2]){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query." WHERE id=? AND time=?");
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("ss",$vals[0],$vals[2])) exit();
    }elseif(!$vals[0] && $vals[1] && !$vals[2]){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query." WHERE date= ? ");
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('s',$vals[1])) exit();
    } // and so one a lot of dublicated code

    // ... 

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    // do smth
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
else
{
    exit();
}
```

I used GET variables for debugging, of course you can use post method. Simple change INPUT_GET into INPUT_POST

**Edit**: Note i had to choose concrete name for columns and table, otherwise $mysqli_prepare() would return false which causes an error because $stmt->bind_param would be called on a boolean. You may should consider this case. You should also close the database and the stmt.

Comment: This needs placeholder values or escaping and it has neither. It's full of [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/) making it highly dangerous code. `filter_input` doesn't render something SQL safe, it just cleans up the rough edges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, it is not injection safe but the question was how to create the sql stmt especially the where clause from a the input of a fromulare with three select tags. And this is a correct answer in a runnable example. Of course it does not cover everthing about the creation of a sql statement. Of course a bind_para should be used. But creating a mysqli_stmt with placeholder and variable bind would be much more complicated but does not focus the real issue. So why downrate :(